# How can I find the value of $c$ given an odd function with these intervals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

An odd function which is defined for all real numbers $x$ has these intervals: $(-3, 5)$, $(-2, -4)$, $(2, c)$.

How can I find the value of $c$? I have no idea on this one.

Comment: What do you mean with "has these intervals ..."? Do you mean that its image is $(-3,5)\cup(-2,-4)\cup(2,c)$?

Comment: There is a pic that shows a table with values of the function. One one side it shows "x" with the x values below it and on the other side it shows h(x) with the other values.

Comment: If it's odd, then $f(-x) = -f(x)$. In other words, if $(a,b)$ is on the image, then so is $(-a,-b)$. This of course follows from the fact that a point $(a,b)$ on the graph of $f$ is actually the same as $(x, f(x))$.

Comment: I think you don't mean "intervals".  I suspect you mean that it passes through the *points* $(-3,5), (-2,4), (2,c)$.

Comment: Are you sure its $(-2,-4)$ and not $(-4,-2)$ or something else? Usually, we write $(a,b)$ where $a < b$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean $(-2,-4)$ as the $(x,y)$ coordinates through which the odd function passes, since otherwise the question does not make any sense. If so, then since $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for an odd function, $f(2)=f(-(-2))=-f(-2)=-(-4)=4$, i.e., $f(2)=4$.